# jQuery css background-image on Safari downloads image again on revisit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm using jQuery to set a background-image to a piece of my website like this:

```
$('.header-image').css('background-image', 'url(/img/image.jpg)');
```

However, when I get back to that page from some other place using Safari, I can see in the network manager that it downloads that image again, whereas Chrome and Firefox do not.

Any idea what is going on?

Edit: The image is 500kb, tried with another at 300kb, produced same result.

Edit: Corrected the quotes around the url, which are present in my code and don't affect the problem I have.

Comment: How big is it? Because i thougt safari has a caching limit lower then other browsers (at least on mobile) might be something similar

Comment: It has different caching implementation that those other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rewrite it

```
$('.header-image').css('background-image', 'url("/img/image.jpg")');
```

Comment: Why? The unquoted syntax is perfectly valid; if it weren't, after all, the image wouldn't load at all.

Comment: I tried it in the console and it won't execute until I added the quotes.

Comment: My bad, I replaced that line without adding quotes when writing this post.